# TValueListEditor with more columns

Tags: delphi, editor, components, delphi-xe, key-value

I'm using a TValueListEditor and i would like to make an IDE property editor like.
Each line can have few kinds of informations :

- String
- Date
- Number
- ComboList

I'm wondering how can i store the type of element and the format for each line.

I try to add 2 columns. But its not working

```
ValueListEditor.ColCount := 4;
ValueListEditor.Cell[4,2] := 'Test';
```

It shows the value Test in the value column (the second column instead of 4).
I was thinking to embeded the values that i need in an object that i will  link (add) to each line. But i didnt' find the way to do so. Even i don't know if it's possible.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TValueListEditor` is specifically designed to handle `name=value` pairs only.  You can't add additional columns to it.  However, you can specify the type of editor used for editing the `value` column. That is handled by the `TItemProp.EditStyle` property for each pair:

- For String input, set the `TItemProp.EditStyle` to `esSimple`.
- For ComboList input, set the `TItemProp.EditStyle` to `esPickList`, and then use the TItemProp.`PickList` property, or the `TValueListEditor.OnGetPickList` event.
- For Numeric input, set the `TItemProp.EditStyle` to `esSimple`, and set the  `TItemProp.EditMask` and `TItemProp.MaxLength` as needed. You can then convert the user's entered `value` to an `Integer` when needed.
- For Date input, you are best off setting the `TItemProp.EditStyle` to `esEllipsis` and then use the `TValueListEditor.OnEditButtonClick` event to display your own `TForm` that has a `TDateTimePicker` on it.  You could do something similar for numeric input if desired, using a `TSpinEdit` or similar component.

Comment: Thx for answering. i implement this way. but when i try to set the VLE.ItemProps[i].EditStyle := TEditStyle.esPickList; if i:=1 it work, but all other value it never work even if i created the lines before. Also it never show the dropdown list arrow.

Comment: @ffert2907: what I described works, I've used it this way before. I recall there are some quirks with it, I'll have to look at my code again and update my answer when I have a free moment.